# Edit the opposite side of a many to many relationship with django generic form

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, many-to-many, m2m

I have two models:

```
 class Actor(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
     event = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, null=True)

 class Event(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
     long_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In a previous question: [Django form linking 2 models by many to many field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503243/django-form-linking-2-models-by-many-to-many-field), I created an EventForm with a save function:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Event

      def save(self, commit=True):
            instance = forms.ModelForm.save(self)
            instance.actors_set.clear()
            for actor in self.cleaned_data['actors']:
                instance.actors_set.add(actors)
            return instance
```

This allowed me to add m2m links from the other side of the defined m2m connection.

Now I want to edit the entry.  I've been using a generic function:

```
def generic_edit(request, modelname, object_id):
       modelname = modelname.lower()
       form_class = form_dict[modelname]
       return update_object(request,
            form_class = form_class,
            object_id = object_id,
            template_name = 'createdit.html'
       )
```

but this pulls in all the info except the many-to-many selections saved to this object.

I think I need to do something similar to this: [Editing both sides of M2M in Admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700202/editing-both-sides-of-m2m-in-admin-page), but I haven't figured it out.

How do I use the generic update_object to edit the other side of many-to-many link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1295/